# slow vpn tunnels speed on high speed network

Tags: networking, vpn, speed, tunnel, iperf3

I have some VMs with minimum network speed of 1G
I need to connect each VM via a split tunnel.
While the raw speed between VMs are 1G but over the tunnels , the speed is down to 10% of the max speed (100M).
My question is that what and where are the bottlenecks?
I am expecting to see near 800M ~ 900M

Tests have been done using `iperf3` and three VPN softwares

1. SoftEther VPN (Dev version v5+)
2. ocserv / openconnect
3. wireguard

NOTE:
There is no users on these servers, CPUs are idle. Servers are connected via split tunnels

sample `utime` of servers

```bash
 21:46:51 up 39 days,  7:49,  2 users,  load average: 0.02, 0.06, 0.25
```

#### server

```bash
iperf3 --server --bind IP
```

#### client

```bash
iperf3 --client IP --time 1 --parallel 1
```

Raw ipv4 to ipv4  (from server A to server B)

```
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr
[  5]   0.00-1.00   sec  1006 MBytes  8.44 Gbits/sec  1473             sender
[  5]   0.00-1.04   sec  1002 MBytes  8.07 Gbits/sec                  receiver
```

SoftEther tap to tap (cascade connection from server A to sever B)

```
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr
[  5]   0.00-1.00   sec   108 MBytes   899 Mbits/sec  1205             sender
[  5]   0.00-1.05   sec   104 MBytes   833 Mbits/sec                  receiver
```

OpenConnect tun to tun (from server A to server B)

```
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr
[  5]   0.00-1.00   sec  97.0 MBytes   814 Mbits/sec  5311             sender
[  5]   0.00-1.04   sec  94.3 MBytes   759 Mbits/sec                  receiver
```

WireGuard

is twice faster near 200M

Both server Debian 11
and Kernel

```
Linux 206 5.10.0-23-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.179-2 (2023-07-14) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Have you checked out the VM (and/or host) resource usage?  Software VPNs need CPU time like any other service, so if the host is already running hot you're going to see poor VPN performance.

Comment: @immortalsquish there is no users on these servers, CPU is idle. connections are split tunnel between servers

Comment: You should still check the CPU usage, while the speed test is running.

Comment: Have ypu tried reducing / clamping mtu?

Comment: @DanielB the speed test is 1 second test `--time 1` I checked that it does not consume CPU

Comment: @davidgo yes a range from 1400 to 1500, and did not help, what number do you recommend ?

Comment: Ah, I didn’t notice. Please retry the test over a longer period to get meaningful results. TCP connections do not start with full speed.